# Icecast authentication via Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, icecast

How can i achieve authentication over Wordpress?

This is what i tried:

```
<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/radio1</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
            <option name="listener_add" value="http://localhost:90/wordpress/wp-login.php"/>
            <option name="auth_header" value="HTTP 200 OK"/>            
    </authentication>       
</mount>
```

But in the log files it says:

> [2015-01-23  12:08:22] INFO auth_url/auth_url.c client auth (http://localhost:90/wordpress/wp-login.php) failed with ""

It seems that the credentials are not forwarded correctly to wordpress...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match what Icecast sends (http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#url) and the WP login form.
I took a brief look at the wordpress default form, it uses:

- log
- pwd

While Icecast sends:

- user
- pass
- (and other fields, see above)

As I mentioned on IRC, all it should take is to slightly modify wp-login.php to additionally accept those parameters and return a reliable header for login success.
Or even better something like http://skookum.com/blog/using-wordpress-as-a-user-and-authentication-database/